# How to call gcloud compute instances create-with-container with container entrypoint arguments

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'd like to create a [compute instance based on a container](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container) with a python entrypoint. The entrypoint requires arguments. As an example, if I'd run the container locally with the command:

```
docker run ${IMAGE_TAG} \
  --arg0=0 \
  --arg1=1
```

What would the gcloud command be to create an instance which automatically runs the entrypoint with the supplied arguments?

I tried something like the following (after pushing the container) but it was unsuccessful. The instance started but it did not run from the entrypoint.

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container \
  ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --machine-type=${INSTANCE_TYPE} \
  --accelerator=${GPU_TYPE} \
  --service-account=default \
  --container-image=${IMAGE_URI} \
  --container-arg="--arg0=0" \
  --container-arg="--arg1=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would ask, how is your ENTRYPOINT defined in your Dockerfile. Are you using the *exec* or the *shell* form?

I would think that you're using the *exec* form as when running it locally you're just appending the two arguments to the docker run command and they are successfully passed over. I mention this as `ENTRYPOINT` defined in *shell* form doesn't accept arguments being passed as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example).

The arguments passed using `--container-arg` should be appended after the ENTRYPOINT in a similar way as when CMD is used to set default values for  `ENTRYPOINT` (for more details see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)).

As John Hanley mentioned, the string `--arg0=0` will be passed to the program appended  to the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`, or to the command specified with `--container-command` as in John Hanley's answer.

I would suggest to check how is the ENTRYPOINT defined in the Dockerfile, to begin troubleshooting what may be causing this. Also you could [check your running processes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) in the VM instance right after creation to see how was the entrypoint executed i.g. `$ docker exec -it test ps aux`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still a bit confused. This is just a toy example - but in the example, the entrypoint is defined as: `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]` and there are no `CMD`s after that. Also the actual arguments (and even how many arguments) aren't known ahead of time. So without docker, I'd use the command: `python3 main.py --arg0=0 --arg1=1 --arg2=2` and I'm just trying to reproduce this. It seems to work okay if I just call `docker run <imagename> --arg0=0 --arg1=1 --arg2=2`. It would make sense that this is just appending "arg0=0 --arg1=1 --arg2=2" as a string

Comment: And if I call `docker run <imagename>`, then `main.py` runs without any arguments. Does adding `CMD []` to the end of the dockerfile and then using something like `--container-arg="--arg0=0 --arg1=1 --someotherarg=blah"` make sense?

Comment: CMD can be used to define default arguments that will be overwritten  by the arguments passed by `docker run` or in this case when using `--container-arg`.

As I'm not quite sure of how `--container-arg` is parsed when using `gcloud compute instances create-with-container` I would stick to separating each argument first.

Comment: I think we have to better understand how  the use  of `--container-arg` parses the argument passed. For this you may run  `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME ps aux` to see the processes in the running container of the VM.  You could paste the output here, and you can do for both your command and as John has suggested and compare how the command is run in the container.

Comment: The container is not being run at all on the vm. I tried boiling things down to the simplest example and still made no headway. Giving up on this for now. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

Normally the `entrypoint` is specified in the Dockerfile when you created the container.

To override this use the `--container-command` and `--container-arg` arguments.

[Passing arguments to the container ENTRYPOINT command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#passing_arguments_to_container_entrypoint_command)

In your `Dockerfile` you specify the program to run and its arguments like this:

```
CMD [ "python", "app.py", "arg1", arg2" ]
```

To override those settings:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container \
  ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --machine-type=${INSTANCE_TYPE} \
  --accelerator=${GPU_TYPE} \
  --service-account=default \
  --container-image=${IMAGE_URI} \
  --containter-command="python"
  --container-arg="app.py" \
  --container-arg="arg1" \
  --container-arg="arg2"
```

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `--arg0=0`. That string unchanged will be passed to the program.

Comment: Thanks. The last line in the dockerfile is `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]`. There are no `CMD` lines. I'm trying to achieve a container that automatically executes main.py with any number of arbitrary arguments supplied. So the gcloud command is meant to just replicate `docker run ${IMAGE_TAG} --arg=1 --anotherarg=x` where the #, names, values of the args aren't known until the gcloud command is called. I would have thought this would be equivalent to just adding `--container-arg`s to the gcloud command. I'll try taking out the entrypoint line and using a gcloud cmd like in your example.